# How to get the first sunday of a month using java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the first sunday of a month .
What i reached is to get all the sundays of one year

```java
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth;

    public static void FindAllSundaysOfTheYear () {
        // Create a LocalDate object that represent the first day of the year.
        int year = 2021;
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1);
        // Find the first Sunday of the year
        LocalDate sunday = now.with(firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));

        do {
            // Loop to get every Sunday by adding Period.ofDays(7) the the current Sunday.
            System.out.println(sunday.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)));
            sunday = sunday.plus(Period.ofDays(7));
        } while (sunday.getYear() == year);
    }
```

The output is

```js
Sunday, January 5, 2020
Sunday, January 12, 2020
Sunday, January 19, 2020
Sunday, January 26, 2020
Sunday, February 2, 2020
Sunday, February 9, 2020
Sunday, February 16, 2020
Sunday, February 23, 2020
...
Sunday, December 6, 2020
Sunday, December 13, 2020
Sunday, December 20, 2020
Sunday, December 27, 2020
```

**How could i get the first first sunday of month ?**

Comment: What is the problem with your code ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the first sunday of each month ?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa That is the goal, it is not a problem. "I want £1 million" is a goal. "The recruiter told me the formatting of my CV is bad" is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add one month on each iteration.

```
public static void findFirstSundayEachMonth() {
    int year = 2021;
    LocalDate curr = LocalDate.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    do {
        System.out.println(curr.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
           .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)));
        curr = curr.plusMonths(1);
    } while (curr.getYear() == year);
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lXRmjp)

Comment: Is there a way to format the date pattern to be 'YYYY-MM-dd'  thanks in advance

Comment: @iota You meant `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd")`, `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")`, or `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`, right? Uppercase `YYYY` is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving this

```
LocalDate sunday = now.with(firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
```

inside the while, and update the `now` month-by-month instead of the `sunday` week-by-week

Comment: If you are going to use code that uses static imports, show the imports. Your answer does not make it clear where firstInMonth comes from

Comment: @Michael I don't know where firstInMonth comes from either, I just supposed it is defined by the OP somewhere else.
If it does what the name suggests, the OP can simply iterate month-by-month and retrieve the first sunday using firstInMonth

edit: alrighty I just read iota answer and firstInMonth is imported from TemporalAdjusters :D

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't notice that. It comes from here btw 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-

Comment: @Michael yup, looks like an easy and concise way to achieve the result, well done Java 

Answer (score 0):

## Stream

We could use a stream to loop through the months of a year.

The [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) class represents a year. Calling [`atMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#atMonth(java.time.Month)) while passing a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum object ([`JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#JANUARY) through `DECEMBER`) returns a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) object. Calling [`YearMonth#atDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#atDay(int)) while passing `1` returns a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object for the first of that month. We can move from that `LocalDate` for the 1st to the first Sunday of that month by using a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html), specifically the one from [`TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( DayOfWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstInMonth(java.time.DayOfWeek)). We get back another `LocalDate` object for then Sunday date.

We collect the first-Sunday `LocalDate` object derived for each month into a list by calling [`.collect( Collectors.toList() )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)). In Java 16 and later, we can replace that list-collector with simply a call to [`Stream#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()).

Something like this code.

```java
List< LocalDate > firstSundayOfEachMonthInYear =
    Stream.of( Month.values() )
    .map( month -> 
        Year
        .of( 2021 )
        .atMonth( month )
        .atDay( 1 )
        .with( 
            TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY )
        ) 
    )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() )   // In Java 16+, shorten to: .toList() 
;
```

Imports

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
 
import java.time.* ;
import java.util.stream.* ;
import java.time.temporal.* ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/VmsZ6D).

> [2021-01-03, 2021-02-07, 2021-03-07, 2021-04-04, 2021-05-02, 2021-06-06, 2021-07-04, 2021-08-01, 2021-09-05, 2021-10-03, 2021-11-07, 2021-12-05]